# How to search for lines using values from comma separated list in any text editor?

Tags: search, text-editors

I have a big file with lots of entries. I want to filter all lines that contain any of the values from comma separated list. 
For example, I have data like:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Praesent tincidunt sapien eu eros porttitor laoreet.
Duis non lacus auctor, lobortis dolor quis, rutrum lectus.
Aenean id est posuere, volutpat enim ac, dictum tortor.
Sed ut risus vehicula, vestibulum urna et, rutrum ex.
Etiam tempus felis et orci volutpat, non convallis magna ultrices.
Duis aliquam est sed ante congue, non cursus massa ultrices.
Nunc nec tellus et ante feugiat accumsan.
Vivamus quis nunc ut purus tincidunt feugiat.
Sed non dolor sit amet ligula feugiat viverra.
```

and want to use filter

```
non,dolor
```

as output I would like to have lines:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Duis non lacus auctor, lobortis dolor quis, rutrum lectus.
Etiam tempus felis et orci volutpat, non convallis magna ultrices.
Duis aliquam est sed ante congue, non cursus massa ultrices.
Sed non dolor sit amet ligula feugiat viverra.
```

Comment: Do you need to do all this from within the text editor or would another program work? Could you use a different separator?